# Make eclipse_debug.py work

Tags: eclipse, pydev, canopy, pythonpath, pyxll

(In Windows 10, I have installed `...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy` that includes `Python 2.7`, `%PATH%` points to Canopy)

I have seen [this link](https://www.pyxll.com/alldocs.html#document-examples/developertools), and want to make interactively debug Python code running in PyXLL work via that `eclipse_debug.py`.

So I have done the following:

1) erase `PYTHONPATH` in the control panel of Windows (as a result, `echo %PYTHONPATH%` returns `%PYTHONPATH%`).

2) modify only the first line of `eclipse_debug.py` to be `eclipse_roots = [r"C:\my_path_to\eclipse"]`.

3) add `eclipse_debug.py` to `pyxll.cfg`

4) define a function `hello`

5) launch `debug servier` in eclipse, and then launch Excel, and then reload PyXLL

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

1) So, it shows that the function `hello` does work.

2) However, I don't see any excel menu item related to debugger, whereas their link promises `This module adds an Excel menu item to attach to the PyDev debugger, and also an Excel macro so that this script can be run outside of Excel and call PyXLL to attach to the PyDev debugger.` In other words, I don't see how interactive debug is enabled here.

Could anyone tell me what this `eclipse_debug.py` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I can tell by looking at it, `eclipse_debug.py` adds the PyDev Remote Debugger (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) to the PYTHONPATH and starts it.

Now, how do you make a Python script such as `eclipse_debug.py` appear as a menu in PyXLL is something I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that it's looking for pydevd but is unable to find it on your python path or where it's looking under the eclipse root. If that's the case there will be some output in the pyxll log file and that will be why the menu item is not appearing.

You should check the log file for errors, and hopefully that will tell you what is going wrong.